# Cake Email Gives an Error

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2, cakephp-2.3

In my Controller file i wrote the following code for attaching an image to the mail,But it gives an error

```
$email->attachments(array('/localhost/projname/app/webroot/img/file.png'));
```

It shows an error like File not found: "&quot

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `IMAGES` constant to get the file path to the images folder:

```
$email->attachments(array(IMAGES.DS.'file.png'));
```

Comment: Thank you Matt,I got solution for this

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got solution for attaching Images

```
$email->attachments(array (
                    array('file'=>ROOT.'/app/webroot/img/car.gif',
                          'mimetype'=>'image/png'
                         ),
                    ));
```